# Representation of Electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I recently came across this figure in purcells book where he shows how moving charge produces magnetic field is there similar way by which in we can draw how a electric field can be produced varying magnetic field i know it is related to lorentz transformation but i can't make physical or intuitive diagram out of it..
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this diagram, a charge has just been moved quickly (close to instantaneously) from one point to another. The corresponding disturbance in the electric field propagates outward at the speed of light. So we end up with three regions: the outer radially arranged fields still perceive the charge to be in its original position, as information about the disturbance has not reached this region of space yet. The inner radially arranged fields are generated by the charge at its current position; the disturbance has already propagated fully to this region of space. The intermediate twisting region connects the two radially arranged regions; this region of space sees the charge as still in motion.

You'll notice that the electric field in the intermediate region has non-zero curl. By Faraday's Law, there is therefore also a non-zero magnetic field within this region (technically, a non-zero *time derivative* of a magnetic field, but the former follows easily from this statement). In contrast, the radial regions have zero curl, so they have constant magnetic field; examining reasonable boundary and initial conditions for the problem (no magnetic field at $t=0$ and at infinity), this leads to there being zero magnetic field in these regions.

Taken together, these facts imply that quickly moving a charge produces a quick magnetic pulse that propagates outward.